# Solve this equation $4^{\log_2(x)}-2^{\log_2(x)}=3^{\log_3(12)}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Solve this equation $4^{\log_2(x)}-2^{\log_2(x)}=3^{\log_3(12)}$

I thought to write $2^{\log_2(x)^2}-2^{\log_2(x)}=3^{\log_3(12)}$. Then is there a way to factorize $2^{\log_2(x)}$? I don't know how to proceed...

Comment: Hint: $\log_n x$ is the inverse of $n^x$.

Comment: Check [basic logarithmic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Analytic_properties) to untangle the exponents. In particular, $(a^2)^{\log_a x} = a^{2{\log_a x}} = a^{{\log_a {x^2}}} = x^2$

Comment: In general, $$\left(a^2\right)^b\ne a^{b^2}.$$

Comment: Hint: $n^{\log_n x}=x$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\log_2 x = t$, then $2^{\log_2 (x)}=2^t=x$. Thus the given equation is
$$x^2-2x=12$$

Comment: why is it equal to 12? what about $3log_3(12)$?

Comment: @anna Suppose $\log_3(12)=m$, then by definition $3^m=12$. Now consider $3^{\log_3(12)}=3^m=12$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

We have $a^{\log_a(b)}=b$ and we have the following:

$$4^{\log_2(x)}=2^{2\log_2(x)}=(2^{\log_2(x)})^2 = x^2$$